# How is the mode of an exponential distribution zero?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

The [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) has a mode of $0$, which, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29), means that $0$ "is the value that is most likely to be sampled". This is not what I would expect, given that the exponential distribution "describes the time between events in a Poisson process".

So, say me getting phone calls is a Poisson process and I get a call every hour on average. How is it that $0$ is the most likely sample? My intuition tells me that $0$ is one of the most *unlikely* samples, or at least much less likely than some number around $1$ hour.

Comment: This about it in these terms. Poisson count happens in the interval $dt$ w/ probability $dt$. So for the first count to happen around $x$, you need no counts to happen previously - so probability is $e^{-x}dx$. Clearly it's maximized at $0$.

Comment: I found this explanation very helpful. https://youtu.be/2kg1O0j1J9c?t=1038

Answer (score 6):

An exponential distribution is that of a continuous random variable.   All particular values it can take have probability mass of zero.

The mode of a continuous random variable is *not* the point where its probability is most massive.   It is where it is most *dense*.

The probability density function of an exponential random variable, $X$ with rate $\lambda$, is:

$$f_X(x)=\lambda \mathsf e^{-\lambda x} \mathbf 1_{x\in[0;\infty)}$$

This is at its maximum when $x=0$.   Hence the mode of the distribution is: $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that the exponential distribution is continuous and that every particular value has zero probability. But that is beside the point. To put it with your terms, the point is that I find it unintuitive that the probability is most dense at $0$. To go back to the phone call example, I would not expect a phone call just after another one, but mode $= 0$ seems to say that this is the most likely thing to happen.

Comment: @rolve obviously nothing is ever really exponentially distributed...

Answer (score 2):

If it's counter intuitive for you, then exponential/Poisson is likely inadequate for the applications that you have in mind.  As explained [elsewhere](http://sherrytowers.com/2015/10/01/probability-distributions-important-to-modelling-in-the-life-and-social-sciences/#exponential):

> Unfortunately, assuming that state sojourn times are exponentially distribute in things like a disease model really isn’t very realistic. (...) A much better probability distribution for sojourn times in compartmental biological and epidemiological models is the Gamma distribution.

So for generalizations, check for example the [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) and [Gamma processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_process).

Answer (score 1):

But the chance of any continuous distribution taking any particular value is 0? The chance it is 3.5 or $\pi$ or $e$ is also 0.

All this means is that: let $X$ have exponential distribution. take any $x>0$, I can find an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $y<\epsilon$

$$P(X\in (x,x+y)) < P(X\in(0,y))$$

What it says is that the chance the distribution takes a value close to 0, is bigger than the chance it take a value close to some other $x$, if we define close to be small enough. I believe that.

Why do you not try to show this and convince yourself?

Answer (score 1):

In a histogram (as opposed to a continuous distribution) the mode is clearly location of the highest bar.

If you construct a histogram (i.e. a step function) that approximates a decaying exponential the highest bar will be the leftmost - the one that starts at $0$.

For skewed distributions like this you will always have mode < median < mean (think family income distribution in the U.S.). The mode may be counterintuitive (to you) because you would rather think about the other two "averages".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question as you coming here and here are my thoughts.

Maybe the exponential distribution is more to model something like this: You have been sited for $3$ days answering non-stop phone calls and suddenly you fix an arbitrary time $t_0$ and look the at the distribution of the next phone call. It is not like the situation of an office employee that people know will answer the phone between $8am$ and $5pm$ and so probably it is unlikely that people will call exactly at $8:00am$. Maybe they will try at $8:01am$ and so it is unlikely to receive a call at exactly $8:00am$.

I often saw examples considering shouting stars. Shouting starts have appeared in the sky for a very long time so if you fix a time $t_0$ it maybe makes sense to expect the appearance of the next shouting star to be distributed according to an exponential distribution.